# c# How do I get response from a redirected POST

Tags: c#, redirect

I am attempting to automate a sequence of manual browser actions in c#. When manually performed, data returned from each POST is used as part of input for next step.  There is one step in the sequence where a POST is redirected, and I can't figure out how to get a response from the redirect URL.  When I try to directly get a response, it is not the data I expect.

The manual sequence is as follows:
1  Enter URL
2  Login Screen appears
3  Login with Username and Password
4  Data Validation Screen appears
5  Enter data to be validated
6  Screen appears to say whether data is valid or invalid
7  Enter next data item to be validated
8  etc.

Using Fiddler, I captured the manual process.  It shows a GET and response after the Login and before Data Validation entry. The Login POST and it's direct response and the subsequent GET and it's response are shown below.
[Fiddler Report on POST and GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mUCC.png)

The code I have been using receives the direct response from the POST (a redirection), but I have been unable to get the response from the redirect URL.  When I try a direct GET to the redirect URL, the response is not correct - probably because it doesn't know about the login done through the original POST URL.  EDIT:  The code I'm using is  shown below:

```
            //Set up the Org Login request
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://XXXXX.com/TEGMemberValidator/Login.aspx"));
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 2;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Referer = "http://XXXXX.com/TEGMemberValidator/Login.aspx";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36";
        //

        //Format the Login POST data
        postData.Clear();
        postData.Append("ScriptManager1=udpnlLogin%7CbtnValidate&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=");
        postData.Append("%2FwEPDwUKLTE5Mzc1ODY1NmRkfiRRWZ9cUsSkYH3z3n3tW2bdIGBeBZ96JphXMbwpaCo%3D");
        postData.Append("&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=");
        postData.Append("5DC834FA");
        postData.Append("&__EVENTVALIDATION=");
        postData.Append("%2FwEdAARHCUjxJ4MNTYwQE%2FK64jes1VXLCZniQEihPDabNrSt9O4sciJO3Hoc68xTFtZGQEiR8T6B3KIlDquMkIoIE61UvzPtKfVQxeZYOtAXnLPv6Ga6a%2FxuXlTLUAOPNsPArMY%3D");
        postData.Append("&name=");
        postData.Append(xnamex);
        postData.Append("&password=");
        postData.Append(xpasswordx);
        postData.Append("&__ASYNCPOST=true&btnValidate=Login");

        //write the Login POST data to the stream
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter
          (request.GetRequestStream()))
            writer.Write(postData.ToString());

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        //Get the response to the POST
        using (sreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            sreturnData = "";
            sreturnData = sreader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //*************
        Console.WriteLine("start  L L L L L L L L L L L L L");
        Console.WriteLine("Login sreturnData:");
        //Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(sreturnData));
        Console.WriteLine(sreturnData);
        Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseUri);
        file.WriteLine(sreturnData);
        file.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("finish L L L L L L L L L L L L L");
        //*************

        //GET response from redirect address
        WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create("http://XXXXX.com/TEGMemberValidator/MemberValidator.aspx");
        request2.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();
        using (sreader = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            sreturnData = "";
            sreturnData = sreader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //*************
        Console.WriteLine("0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0");
        Console.WriteLine(response2.ResponseUri);
        Console.WriteLine(sreturnData);
        //*************
```

My problem/question is how can I get the response from the redirect URL that Fiddler was able to capture?

Comment: What is the response status code you get from the redirect URL? Are you using basic HTTP authentication? If so you may need to include the authorization header in that request. Also please don't link to a picture of your code, but include the code directly in the question, people are more likely to answer when they see the code directly.

Comment: Response from redirect is 200.

Comment: Have added basic HTTP authentication - no change

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to add code in comment or edit original post to add code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Figured out how to ad code.  Edited original post to add code.

Comment: But what is the response you get after requesting at the redirect address? You only mention "the response is not correct" and assume that it has to do with login credentials - is there any evidence of this in the response status code? Good to see you got the code added!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution - Don't forget the cookies!

I forgot to add .CookieContainer to each of the requests to the web.  Because of that, the redirect did not know that my Login had been validated and it kept sending me back to before my Login and kept giving me the appropriate response for that level of the process.

Add CookieContainer CC=new CookieContainer   before first call to web.
Add request.CookieContainer = CC   to each request.